# Use calculated cell reference in formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, cell, subtotal

I want to use SUBTOTAL to calculate the mean within a range without hard coding in the cell references.

I an currently using the standard:

```
=SUBTOTAL(1, A2:A11)
```

But I want Excel to recognise which cells in column A start and end possessing values. So I can specify cell A11 in a separate cell using:

```
=ADDRESS(MATCH(9.99999E+307, A:A), 1)
```

Which returns "$A$11". However, If I combine the above equations thus:

```
=SUBTOTAL(1, A2:ADDRESS(MATCH(9.99999E+307, A:A), 1))
```

I get an error. I have also tried INDIRECT in combinations with these but that does not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) to supply the latter half of the cell range.

```
=SUBTOTAL(1, A2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1e99, A:A)))
```